# Using EXISTS or IN for my Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a stored procedure that will receive three values from a forms application. The values are "biz_abbrev", "comp_Name" and "biz_Type". The Stored Procedure would then return a "biz_Number".
Depending on the value of the "biz_abbrev", the stored procedure will decide what table to Search out of two tables. Each table have similar columns including the two above namely "comp_Name" and "biz_Type". The biz_abbrev is generated by the application and it either generates "abbrev1" or "abbrev2". 
The two tables in the database are named "Tbl_Avi" and "Tbl_Marine".
Below is my Stored Procedure

```
USE [Reports_DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetBizNo] 
    @biz_Type nvarchar(255),
    @comp_Name nvarchar(255),
    @biz_abbrev nvarchar(50)
    AS
    DECLARE @biztemptable TABLE (
    biz_Number nvarchar(255));

Insert into @biztemptable

SELECT (
        CASE @biz_abbrev 
        WHEN 'abbrev1' THEN (
        SELECT DISTINCT av.biz_Number FROM dbo.Tbl_Avi av WHERE @comp_Name =       av.Company_Name AND @biz_Type = av.Business_Type)
        ELSE (
        SELECT DISTINCT mar.biz_Number FROM dbo.Tbl_Marine mar WHERE @comp_Name = mar.Company_Name AND @biz_Type = mar.Business_Type)
        END)
SELECT * FROM @biztemptable
```

The Stored Procedure runs well until when a Table has multiple biz_Number for the same Company_Name and biz_Type i.e
**Table a**
Company_Name     biz_Type  biz_Number   turnover
   Comp1            AA         123       1000000
   Comp1            AA         123       1200000
   Comp2            AB         345       1230000
   Comp2            AB         345       1450000

**Table b**
Company_Name     biz_Type  biz_Number   turnover
   Comp1            AA         123       1000000
   Comp1            AA         124       1200000
   Comp2            AB         345       1230000
   Comp2            AB         346       1450000

Table B will not run but will display the error

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

How would I use EXISTS or IN on the above statement?

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory, your subquery is returning more than 1 row. Maybe you could use top 1 instead? It kind of depends on what you are trying to accomplish and what the business rules are. For best results you might take a look here to improve your question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I want to get all the results if there are more than one unique result

Comment: Then you need to change your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do here but I think you need something very close to this.

```
Insert into @biztemptable (biz_Number)
SELECT DISTINCT av.biz_Number 
FROM dbo.Tbl_Avi av 
WHERE @comp_Name = av.Company_Name 
    AND @biz_Type = av.Business_Type
    and @biz_abbrev = 'abbrev1'

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT mar.biz_Number 
FROM dbo.Tbl_Marine mar 
WHERE @comp_Name = mar.Company_Name 
    AND @biz_Type = mar.Business_Type
    and @biz_abbrev <> 'abbrev1'
```